# How to call a ngrx selector inside an another selector (which accepts a parameter to compute)

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-selectors, memoized-selectors

I created two selectors

1. To get all networks -
   `export const getAllNetworks = createSelector(getState, state => state.networks);`
2. get devices for each network

   ```
     createSelector(getAllNetworks, network => {
       const selectedNetwork = network.filter(net => net.id === networkId);
       return selectedNetwork[0]?.allDevices;
     });
   ```

I wanted to create a third selector which uses the first selector to get networks and then uses the second selector to get additional data

```
export const something = createSelector(
  getAllNetworks, (networks) => {
    networks.map(

      // How can I call the selector selectNetworkDevices by passing the network ID here and get the devices [ex: selectNetworkDevices(network.id)]

    )
  }
)
```

Comment: aren't you getting an error in your 2nd selector? how does it get the networkId?

Comment: @Andres2142 getAllNetworks - would give me an array of network objects which has an id property on each of them.                                              the first and second selectors are just examples. all I am trying to do is to call another selector inside a create selector (the third one)

Answer (score 2):

You can use different selectors based on others like this:

```js
export const selectUsers = createSelector(getState, (state) => state.users);

export const selectAccounts = (accountId?: string) => 
 createSelector(getState, (state) => 
   accountId ? state.accounts[accountId] : {}
 );

export const something = (accountId?: string) => 
  createSelector(
    selectUsers,
    selectAccounts(accountId),
    (usersData, accountsData) => {
      // some logic
      return accountId ? 'an account id was provided' : 'no-id'
    }
  )
```

In your component you could call this selector either providing the parameter or not:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.select(something());  // without parameter
  this.store.select(something('anAccountId')); // with parameter
}
```

More information here: [link](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-for-multiple-pieces-of-state)

**UPDATE:**

We have 2 `selectors`, `selectAccounts` and `myOtherSelector`. For `myOtherSelector`, instead of calling directly the `selectAccounts` selector, you can reuse its logic by calling its callback function.

```js
export const selectUsers = createSelector(getState, (state) => state.users);

export const selectAccounts = (accountId?: string) => 
 createSelector(getState, (state) => filterAccount(state));

export const myOtherSelector = createSelector(
  selectUsers,
  (users) => {
    if (users) return users;

    // here, you are reusing the callback function related to
    // another selector
    const accountFiltered = filterAccount([]);
    return accountFiltered;
  }
)

function filterAccount(accounts): Account {
 //...some complex logic 
 // ...
 // ...
 return account[index];
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify my question once again, There are two selectors you mentioned, one is **selectAllNetworks** and second one is **selectAllDevicesById**

Now I would like to create a new selector

Comment: `export const newSelector = createSelector(selectAllNetworks, (networks) => {
  networks.forEach(
    (network) => {
      //want to do some business logic here and at some point I wanted to get the devices for each network and I want to use the second selector selectAllNetworks
      // How do I call the second selector here
      selectAllNetworks(network.id) // This is returning a memoized function but not the devices
    }
  )
  })`
You can ask me why do you need to use the second selector to get devices, you can just do network.devices, This is just a example use case I mentiond

Comment: The above is just an example use case, my main question is, How do I call another selector in the create selector.

Comment: I understood this one @Andres2142. what if the second selector takes a id as a input parameter.

Comment: If the second selector is this one,

`export const selectAccountsOfUsers = (id: string) => createSelector(
  selectUsers,
  (users) => {
    const user = users.find((usr) => usr.id === id);
    return user?.accounts;
  })`

Then How can we use both the selectors without passing the ID

Comment: Sorry  @Andres2142, Let me explain my question again. There is one selector [ ** selector 1 ** ]which takes input (id) as a parameter and returns some value,

I have one more selector [ ** Selector 2 **] created using create selector and in its projector, I would like to call the selector1 and pass the id parameter to get some value.

I was expecting the call would return some value, but the selector 1 call is returning a memoized function.

Comment: Andres2142 - Any suggestions on how to achieve it?

Comment: @kireeti9, I hope this last updated I did solves your issue